# Displaying arrays with processing?

Tags: processing

So the code I'm writing is to output an array on the screen. The example I have been basing off my problem is [here](https://processing.org/examples/array2d.html) in which there are dots that are an equal distance from each other. If you're too lazy to click the link, this is the code:

```
   float[][] distances;
   float maxDistance;
   int spacer;

   void setup() {
   size(640, 360);
   maxDistance = dist(width/2, height/2, width, height);
   distances = new float[width][height];
   for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      float distance = dist(width/2, height/2, x, y);
       distances[x][y] = distance/maxDistance * 255;
     }
   }
   spacer = 10;
   noLoop();  // Run once and stop
 }

 void draw() {
  background(0);
  // This embedded loop skips over values in the arrays based on
  // the spacer variable, so there are more values in the array
  // than are drawn here. Change the value of the spacer variable
  // to change the density of the points
  for (int y = 0; y < height; y += spacer) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x += spacer) {
     stroke(distances[x][y]);
     point(x + spacer/2, y + spacer/2);
   }
 }
}
```

What I have coded only returns a white window. This is that code:

```
    float []  arrays = {1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0};;
    int spacer=50;
    PFont font;
    int row;
    int col;

    void setup(){
      size(640,360);
      font = createFont("Arial",1);
      textFont(font,50);

}

    void draw(){
    background(255,255,255);
    for(int i = 0; i<col; i++){
       for(int j=0;j<row;j++){
          String myArray = nfp(arrays[i*col+j],1,2);
          fill(0,0,0);
          text(myArray, i+spacer/2, j+spacer/2);
       }
     }
}
```

I'm super new to processing, and stuff. Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 1):

In your code, i don't see your `col` and `row` initializated.

You should do it in `void setup()`

Maybe that's the reason why you are not seeing anything on your window, because if this two variables has no value your two loops doesn't execute. In the example you provide, use `width` and `height` that are *"system variables"* that return the size of the window (640x360 in the example)

Also, watch out this:

```
float []  arrays = {1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0};; (two semicolons)
```